# How to conditionally update documents in mongoose on existing data?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing a MERN app, and the mongoose schema's looks like this,

1. Installment Schema

```js
const InstallmentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // ... other schema properties
  noOfInstallments: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  }
})
```

2. Student Schema

```js
const studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  // ... other schema properties
  totalInstallmentsToBeIssued: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  installments: [
    {
      installmentId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'installment',
        required: true
      },
      noOfInstallments: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

When an installment is issued, I wanted to add it to the installments collection and conditionally update array of subdocuments in the students collection.

For Example, let's say an Installment with `noOfInstallment` of 4 is issued, `totalInstallmentsToBeIssued` is 40, and the sum of `noOfInstallments` in the array of subdocument  is 38 in students collection.Then a subdocument with `noOfInstallments` as 2 should be added to the array of subdocuments.

Context: I'm trying to cap the amount of installments issued to the students by `totalInstallmentsToBeIssued`

How can I achieve this query, with a single request to the database (or at most 2 requests)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. If you have 40 students, you can issue 40 installments. You want to keep track of the

(1) no. of installments issued

(2) no. of installments TO BE issued

???

Perhaps you can check out mongoose instance or static methods.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/introduction-to-mongoose-for-mongodb-d2a7aa593c57/

Comment: No, the installment schema is to keep track of how the admin issues the installments. Let's say the admin issues 4 i.e `noOfInstallments`, all the students who are having less than (40 - 4) as the installments should get 4 installments. and the others won't get it, also there could be instances where a particular student has been given 38 installments so the balance of 2 installments should be issued for him, those installments are recorded in the `installments` array of subdocuments in each student document.